# Jackson unable to convert json to list of maps

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

In my spring-boot project, I have a controller

```
@RequestMapping(path = { "/multiCommunication" }, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Object> multiCommunication(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listOfInput){ //code}
```

I am unable to access the list as Jackson is unable to cast my request.

Request:

> [
>     {
>       "type": "HPMRE",
>       "pipFirstName": "ABC"
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "HPMRE",
>       "pipFirstName": "XYZ"
>     }
>   ]

Is there something wrong with the JSON?

I have tried making a model class which has a variable of type `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` Still jackson is unable to cast it.

Comment: Are you getting a ClassCastException? Share the exact error and the line of code you are getting the error

Comment: Hi Vineeth, Even if I just print the list, the list is empty.

Comment: I thought you are not able to cast the request.... if the list is empty, how are you expecting to cast it?

Comment: Vineeth, JSON to list casting is what I am talking about

Comment: try taking this string and parse it to a list using ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`@RequestMapping(path = { "/multiCommunication" }, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Object> multiCommunication(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listOfInput){`

Answer (score 0):

try changing the HashMap to a LinkedHashMap:

```
@RequestMapping(path = { "/multiCommunication" }, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Object> multiCommunication(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> listOfInput){ 
//code
}
```